# Expected Value of converging Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, expected-value

Currently, I am working on the following problem:

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables, which suffice $X_n \overset{\mathcal{D}}{\rightarrow} X$. Proof the following inequality
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(|X|) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(|X_n|).
\end{align*}

My thoughts so far are:

The function $f_k(x) = \min \{|x|,k \}$ is continuous and bounded for all $k$. Therefore $\mathbb{E}(f_k(X)) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(f_k(X_n))$ holds. For all $k$: $f_k(X_n) \leq |X_n|$ which implies $\mathbb{E}(f_k(X)) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(f_k(X_n)) \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(|X_n|)$.

I am stuck at this point because I can't find the right relation between $\mathbb{E}(f_k(X))$ and $\mathbb{E}(|X|)$. I believe that if $k \to \infty$ then they should be equivalent but this doesn't necessarily solve the problem. I would really appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: This follows from the Skorokhod representation theorem and Fatou's lemma.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the monotone convergence theorem, i.e.,
$$
\mathsf{E}|X|=\mathsf{E}\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(X)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\mathsf{E}f_k(X)\le \liminf_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{E}|X_n|.
$$